# Is the waiting for review and the result of the request considered part of the flow of events for submitting the request?

Tags: use-case

A company wants to build an online recruitment system. The logged-in person can add the recruitment application, and attach his CV and some documents.
He will wait for the application to be reviewed by the HR, perhaps for a few days.
The company requests to continue the recruitment process or informs that the application is rejected.

My question:

Are the **waiting application to be reviewed** and the **company’s response** considered within the flow of events for the **add employment application** use case?

If the answer is **Yes**:

Does the Basic Flow includes both responses (**continue recruitment process** and **rejection of the application**)
or is **rejection of the application** considered within the Alternative Flows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are the "waiting application to be reviewed" and the "company’s response" considered within the flow of events for the "add employment application" use case?

That depends on the level of abstraction and the viewpoint you have in that use case.

If the use case is written from a very high-level viewpoint, the company's response, any subsequent interview rounds up to the actual hiring could be part of the use case.

If the use case is written more from a viewpoint of the interactions that a user has with the software application, then it might be better to restrict each use case to the flow of events that would typically happen in a single sitting/session with the application.

A step "waiting for application to be reviewed" should definitely **not** be part of a use case. It is not an action someone (or the system) takes within the interaction. It is at best an indication of time between the steps of the use case. Such waiting times are usually left implicit.

---

> Does the Basic Flow includes both responses ("continue recruitment process" and "rejection of the application") or is "rejection of the application" considered within the Alternative Flows?

The Basic Flow shows only a single path through the use case, typically the most common path to a successful result.

The Alternative Flows show other ways within the use case that the user can reach their goal.

If the user cannot achieve their goal, then at some point they deviate into an Exception Flow.

Assuming the the user's goal is that they are hired, then the rejection of their application means they go into an Exception Flow at that point (which probably quickly terminates the use case).

Comment: This pretty much what I would say. I would add, though, that some ways of capturing use cases don't differentiate between "alternative flow" and "exception flow". Everything is either the "basic flow" or "main success scenario" or an "extension" or "alternate flow" that deviates from the main success scenario at one point.

Answer (score 1):

The use-case `Add employment application` seems to correspond to a rather precise and elementary goal: once it’s added, it’s done. Nothing suggest that there could me more behind it.

If it would be `Apply for employment`, it would suggest that there is a bigger picture:  the application process is broader than adding an application: it could include the reply, invitations to interviews, etc.

Ultimately, you decide what’s in it, in your narrative that describes the case. But it should be consistent with the with the use-case name.

Other use-case elements play a role as well:

- if the use-case has two actors, the candidate as primary actor and the recruiter as secondary actor, you’d strongly suggest some kind of feedback, since the secondary actor is involved in addressing the goals of the primary actor.
- if there’s only one actor, I’d tend to imagine that if there’s a feedback, it’ll be some kind of delivery receipt.

Waiting is not an action. Waiting is the consequence of a reply that is not immediate. I’d strongly advise not mention it at all. If you’d nevertheless want it:

- be aware that "waiting"  would strongly suggest active waiting, i.e the user stays in front of the system until the reply is there.
- other terms may better reflect what the user is doing all that time, e.g. monitoring the application, checking for response, etc...

So, since use-cases are a communication tool, it is important to invest some time choosing accurate and precise terms to name things and reduce misunderstandings.